# Keep next letter in replace mode?

Tags: replace

If I'm using replace mode, but I want to keep one or a few characters in a row of the text I am replacing, is there an easy way to skip forward rather than retyping the characters or exiting replace mode and moving and re-entering replace mode?

For example, let's say I'm editing the following text:

```
Tue Jun 11 20:08:07
```

And I want to change it to:

```
Wed Jun 12 20:08:07
```

I can do this by typing `RWed Jun 12<Esc>` but that seems unwieldy.  I can do it as two separate edits, but I run into this use case often and it seems to me there may be a Vim feature just for this task.

Since I recently learned about `:help i_ctrl-y`, a feature which blew my mind, I thought it worth asking.  Ideally the feature I'm hoping for would allow for repeating the entire replace action with the `.` key, including preserving the characters in the middle (whatever they might be).

Answer (score 1):

You want to skip `Jun` , so you must find a way to move cursor to `11`.

You want to use dot repeat, so `<c-o>` is not an option, as it always splits undo.

That leave you only the arrow keys. To stop it from breaking undo, custom map is necessary:

```
inoremap <Left>  <C-G>U<Left>
inoremap <Right> <C-G>U<Right>
inoremap <C-Left>  <C-G>U<C-Left>
inoremap <C-Right> <C-G>U<C-Right>
```

The replace keystrokes are:
 <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>W</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>c-right</kbd><kbd>c-right</kbd><kbd>right</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, it's dot repeatable.

[:h i_CTRL-G_U](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-G_U) stopped next cursor movement from breaking undo. Read after the linked doc if you want to know how to achieve the same behavior for `<home>` and `<end>`.

<s>Personally i prefer multiple edits and macro repeat.</s>

Answer (score 0):

You can bind some keys in insert mode to move to the next word like vim-rsi plugin does making vim readline binding aware or use built-in arrow keys. This would be dot repeatable.

Or you can `RWed<C-o>/11<CR>12` to replace Tue to Wed, goto normal mode for a single command, search for 11 and continue replacing 11 to 12.

For your example though I would just go for `cwWed<ESC><C-a>` -- change word Tue to Wed and increase next number by 1. But that is not dot repeatable.

Comment: Or `RWed<C-o>/11/e<CR>2`. As dedowsdi mentions, this has probelms with .